# Can make OL draggable but not child LIs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to:

1. Drag an item from one div to a target div
2. Once it is contained in the target div, make it draggable within the bounds of the target div

Working from the [Droppable Shopping cart demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart) I have been able to:

1. Drag item to target DIV
2. Within target div, make parent list draggable
3. But not make list item itself draggable.

JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Fp25w/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp25w/2/)

I want each list item to be draggable as a separate entity.

Here is my mark-up:

```
   <div id="catalog">
     <div>
       <ul>
         <li>Lolcat Shirt</li>
         <li>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
         <li>Buckit Shirt</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div id="cart">
   <div class="ui-widget-content">
     <ol>
       <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
     </ol>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my function:

```
$( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
    }
});
$( "#cart li" ).draggable({
    containment:"document",
    cursor:"move"
});
```

Targeting the list items with #cart li is not working- nothing happens. Same for any variation I can think of for targeting the lis individually. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I can now see that what is happening is that the LIs created by dropping items into the shopping cart do not gain the class=ui-draggable attribute needed. Now I am looking for a way to make sure the mark-up generated by dropping goes from this:

```
    <li>List item</li>
```

to this:

```
    <li class="ui-draggable">List item</li>
```

Here is the line that generates this:

```
 $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
```

How can I change it so that the LIs receive the class of ui-draggable?

EDIT 2:

Simply adding the class won't work, as I just discovered by trying addClass(). Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because they are dynamically added contents, you need to call `draggable` for each of the dynamically added content

```
var cartlidragopts = {
    containment:"document",
    cursor:"move"
};

$( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this ).draggable(cartlidragopts);
    }
});
$( "#cart ol li" ).draggable(cartlidragopts);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8fa8/1/)

Comment: We found different approaches, but the answer is correct: for dynamically added contents, draggable needs to be called for each dynamic item.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make #cart Draggable within the Drop function, like so:

```
$( "#cart ul" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
    $("#cart li").addClass("ui-draggable");
    $("#cart ul li").draggable({containment:"document", cursor:"move"});
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fp25w/4/